# How we can get the author ID by its Name

Tags: author

How can i retrieve the author id if i have its name.

I have fornt end form any user can enter the author name to filter the posts by author name so after that how can i get author id. Or there is any other way to write the query so that it return the posts which is posted by specific authors. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

[`get_user_by`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_by) will get you the user data by 'id', 'slug', 'email', or 'login'.

'slug' is the user_nicename.

```
$user = get_user_by('slug','nicename');
```

However, I am not sure what you mean by 'name'. There are other plausible 'name' fields, not all of them required. There is the `display_name` for example.

To search fields like `user_nicename` you will need to create a new [`WP_User_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query).

```
$args= array(
  'search' => 'Display Name',
);
$user = new WP_User_Query($args);
```

The default columns searched appear to be based on [the type of data in the search field](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/user.php#L472) but you can restrict to particular fields by using the `search_fields` parameter.

```
$args= array(
  'search' => 'Display Name', // or login or nicename in this example
  'search_fields' => array('user_login','user_nicename','display_name')
);
$user = new WP_User_Query($args);
```

Comment: Yes here [name] means [display_name]. Basically i get the author [display_name] from user and on the bases of that [dis_play] name i show the posts the posts.  > $user = get_user_by('slug', 'nicename');  Can i put the [display_name] instead of [nicename] here?

Answer (score 0):

Strange, because I found it difficult the correct answer to this, in turn anyway, it's a simple thing:
Firstly you need get the author's name (So this now you've got it this way either, in this example I get the comment author's name):

`$author = get_comment_author( $comment_ID );`

And now the ID by its name:

`$the_user = get_user_by('login', '' . $author . '');
$the_user_id = $the_user->ID;`