# How we can get the user id by its display_name

Tags: users, user-meta

I have user `display_name` and with this I want to get the `id` of that user.

So, how can I get the user id?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the following function:

```
function get_user_id_by_display_name( $display_name ) {
    global $wpdb;

    if ( ! $user = $wpdb->get_row( $wpdb->prepare(
        "SELECT `ID` FROM $wpdb->users WHERE `display_name` = %s", $display_name
    ) ) )
        return false;

    return $user->ID;
}
```

This is the same code [`get_user_by()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/get_user_by) uses, but since that function only allows `ID`, `slug`, `email` or `login` we have to create a new function.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`WP_User_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query).

```
$args= array(
  'search' => 'Display Name', // or login or nicename in this example
  'search_fields' => array('user_login','user_nicename','display_name')
);
$user = new WP_User_Query($args);
```

Just answered one very similar to this: [How we can get the author ID by its Name](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/89990/how-we-can-get-the-author-id-by-its-name/89994#89994)

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working for me

Comment: @EHerman: without more information I couldn't tell you why.

Comment: dump of `$user` shows that `display_name` is not in sql query. Use another answer to enable it http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/201779/how-to-get-user-by-display-name-with-wp-user-query

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that this has been mentioned, probably because it searches display_name as well as email address, URL, ID and username, this is more than required but worked well for my particular use case.

```
function get_user_id_by_search( $search_term ) {
    $user = get_users(array('search' =>  $search_term));

    if (!empty($user))
        return $user[0]->ID;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Completely untested, but I can't see anything in the code why it wouldn't work to use [`get_users()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users) with a meta query:

```
$users = get_users( array(
    'meta_key' => 'display_name',
    'meta_value' => 'John Doe'
) );

$user = ( ( isset( $users[0] ) ? $users[0] : false );

$user_id = ( $user ? $user->ID : false );
```

Comment: display_name is not on the usermeta table but is a dedicated column the users table.

Answer (score 0):

the wordpress user query by default doesn't allow the display_name in search column even it's added in , here is a solution http://manchumahara.com/2014/04/03/search-user-by-display-name-in-wordpress-sitewide/

Example:

```
$args= array(
  'search' => 'Display Name', // or login or nicename in this example
  'search_fields' => array('user_login','user_nicename','display_name')
);
$user = new WP_User_Query($args);
```

The above query will not find for display_name

you need to use this filter

```
add_filter('user_search_columns', 'user_search_columns_bd' , 10, 3);

function user_search_columns_bd($search_columns, $search, $this){

    if(!in_array('display_name', $search_columns)){
        $search_columns[] = 'display_name';
    }
    return $search_columns;
}
```